# Xamarin Compilation warnings for duplicate managed type found (Android.Support.Design and Google Play Services)

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services

I'm currently working on a project that makes use of both the Android.Support.Design and I just added Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location. Since adding the latter nuGet package, I have 41 warnings and 98 errors and compilation and build no longer works. The warnings are mostly of the type:

```
Warning: Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and 
Java types must be unique. First Type:
'Android.Support.V4.View.IOnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor,
Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type:
'Android.Support.V4.View.IOnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor,
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Whereas the errors are of following nature:

```
error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient does not
exist com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
(proj) javac
```

I'm really lost how this is happening and what I need to do in order to get my project to compile again. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the nuget versions?

Comment: @SushiHangover Google Play Service version = 42.1021.1 and Support.Design = 25.4.0.2

Comment: I have the same combo in one of my app and am also using those versions (updated to 25.4.0.2 yesterday when it was released) and do not see any of those problems. Clean the solution (and manually delete the `obj` directory contents if needed) and try a rebuild....

Comment: @SushiHangover The clean solved it! Thank you so much! Should have thought about doing that earlier. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @SushiHangover thank you. the clean worked for me too.